# how do you use multiple arguments with gsub? (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I need to add multiple arguments to the `gsub` parenthesis, but whatever I try it doesn't seem to work.

```
# encoding: utf-8
# !/usr/bin/ruby

# create an empty array
original_contents = []
# open file to read and write
f = File.open("input.txt", "r")
# pass each line through the array
f.each_line do |line|
# push edited text to the array

 original_contents << line.gsub(/[abc]/, '*')

end
f.close

new_file = File.new("output.txt", "r+")
new_file.puts(original_contents)
new_file.close
```

I need it so I can do a lot of different search and replaces like this:

```
original_contents << line.gsub(/[abc]/, '*' || /[def]/, '&' || /[ghi]/, '£')
```

Of course I know this code doesn't work but you get the idea. I've tried using an array for each argument but it ends up printing the text into the output file multiple times.
Any ideas?

Comment: Just run `gsub` multiple times, i.e. `line.gsub(/[abc]/, '*').gsub(/[def]/, '&').gsub(/[ghi]/, '£')`.

Comment: @HolgerJust Yes You are correct please post it as answer

Comment: Brilliant, thankyou! i thought i tried this way before but i must have done it wrong

Answer (score 0):

As Holger Just said, I also suggest you run `gsub` multiple times. You can make the code a bit prettier when you store the replacements in a hash and then iteratively apply them to the string with `Enumerable#reduce`.

```
replacements = {
  /[abc]/ => '*',
  /[def]/ => '&',
  /[ghi]/ => '£'
}

f = File.open("input.txt", "r")

original_contents = f.lines.map do |line|
  replacements.reduce(line) do |memo, (pat, replace)|
    memo.gsub(pat, replace)
  end
end

f.close

new_file = File.new("output.txt", "r+")
new_file.puts(original_contents)
new_file.close
```